# Java inheritance: Reducing visibility in a constructor vs inherited method

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, constructor, access-modifiers

In the following code, the constructor of `Child` has reduced visibility from `public` to `private`, which is allowed.  The inherited methods, such as `test()`, cannot have reduced visibility.  Why does Java operate this way?

```
class Parent { 
        public Parent(){}

       public void test()  
        {  
            System.out.print("parent test executed!");  
        }
}

class Child extends Parent{  

    private Child(){}

    private void test(){
        System.out.print("child test executed!"); 
    }

    }
```

Comment: This [link](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_method_overriding_in_java_programming) gives an explanation for why an overriding method can't have a more restrictive access (go to about the middle of the text).  The answer discusses methods that are called polymorphically.  Constructors aren't called polymorphically, so the same reasons wouldn't apply.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Constructors are not inherited, so `Child()` doesn't override `Parent()`.

As for the methods, if you have (if `Child()` were `public`)

```
Parent p = new Child();
p.test();
```

Had it been allowed, this would be invoking a `private` method. So narrowing the access while overriding is not permitted.

Comment: if the constructors are not inherited, making `Parent` constructor `Private`, the child class constructor has following error : `Implicit super constructor Parent() is not visible. Must explicitly invoke another 
 constructor`

Comment: Well, that's another issue.  Every constructor calls a superclass constructor (except for `Object` itself), whether there is an explicit call or not.  If there is no explicit call, then Java inserts an implicit call to the no-arg superclass constructor as the first statement in the subclass constructor.  If the superclass constructor is `private`, then of course it's not accessible.

Comment: so constructors are not inherited, but there is always a call to superclass constructor (either implicit or explicit) just to initialize the fields correct?

Comment: @brainstorm "just to initialize the fields"... That's the usual purpose, to initialize fields belonging to the superclass.  However, if you write a no-argument constructor in the superclass, you can put anything you want in it--initialize some fields, display some output, send a message to another computer, erase the hard disk--and it will be called implicitly by the subclass constructor if it isn't `private` and you don't have an explicit `super(...)` constructor call.

Answer (score 1):

When extending a class you are stating that your class  is an extension of the parent class ("IS-A" relationship). What this means is that your class will have all methods of your parent class. This is the same as implementing an interface in java except you gain the method definitions (and fields) from your parent and not just methods declared in the interface. In interfaces constructors are not present because they are not methods. Constructors are special as they belong entirely to the class they are declared on. They declare how to construct only themselves.

In order to construct an object you must know that objects class.

```
    class A {
        private message;
        private A() {
            message = "You created an A";
        }

        public A(String message) {
            this.message = message; 
        }

        public void printMessage() {
            System.out.println(message);
        }

        public static A createAnA() {
            return new A();
        }
    }

    class B extends A {
        public B() {
            super("You created a B");
        }
    }

A anA = new B();  // This will work
A anotherA = new A(); // This is not allowed as the constructor is private
A yetAnotherA = A.createAnA(); // This works too
```

So when we constructed B we can say that it is an A. Even though the constructor A is private this is due the constructor not being a part of the interface. The only thing we are saying about B when we assign it to a field of type A is that it has the methods of declared in A. In this case `printMessage` and `createAnA`.

That is why you can make the constructor private without changing the definition of the class. Now, why are you not allowed to make the method private when overriding a parents signature. This comes to having varying definitions of the `[class].method()`. Let's say that you could make your method private. Let's say that you declared a printMssage in the B class. Your reasoning is that you want that method for your use only inside the method and you want your parents printMessage to be used when called externally. Now, you wrote a method like this in the B class.

```
public void adjustMessage(String additional) {
    message = getMessage() + additional();
}
```

Which version of get message would be executed? Your private one or the public one of your parents? The Java dispatcher would of course choose the public one as it is the one declared in the interface. So we we look at this example we can see if you did make your method have different a lower privilege your method could never be dispatched too which would just make things confusing for the reader.

This is a very good question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. you cannot have private constructor in superclass. your code as such has compilation errors

Comment: You can have private constructors in your super class. However, if you  extend that class you must have some kind of access to construct it. I have corrected the example code to demonstrate that point as well.